# NPM build with version number

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-scripts

Is there a way to update the version number of my react app package.json version variable via command line? Maybe with npm build or before/after npm build?

I have a build server that will run npm build and then deploy to production. I want to be able to update the version number of my application either during the build process or before it as part of the build pipeline. I am planning to just use the last git commit sha as the version number.

Is there a command that I am missing? I have had a look at npm version but I believe that is for just updating packages. I could be wrong.

Comment: you mean the semver management command [npm version (major|minor|patch)](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-version)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans does this allow me to set a unique version or just increment the semantic version?

Comment: If you're using npm, you should absolutely only _ever_ use semver. If you need build numbers, that's what patch is for (and if you need build dates, that's in the tag commit and trivial to look up)

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```bash
npm version [major|minor|patch]
```

to bump the version variable on `package.json` using cli.

If you want to combine it with the build, you can use;

```bash
npm version [major|minor|patch] && react-scripts build
```

#### References

1. [npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-version) for syntax documentation.
2. [semvar.org](https://semver.org/) for version notation.